# Check database stores includes same units from session PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to check sessionbasket before buying (and check if database store includes same units from session )

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] AS $key => $qty){
    $sizes_id[] = $qty['units'];
}
```

output from session:

```
Array(
    [0] => 1 (units)
    [1] => 5 (units)
)
```

lets assume that there is max 2 units in db, and 5 in session. I need to loop through the database and check if session is equal session output. if true, insert into db else, redirect front

Comment: Please clarify. You want to check if the data in your session is still the same as in the database?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution.

```
        foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] AS $sizes_id => $qty){

            $in_stock = $db->GetScalar("SELECT s.units FROM products_sizes s 
                                        INNER JOIN products p ON p.product_id = s.product_id
                                        WHERE s.id = '$sizes_id'
            ");             
     }
```

This was the part i was searching for, and it works ->

```
     if ($in_stock == 0 || $_SESSION['cart'][$sizes_id]['units'] > $in_stock){
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort your units array in descending order.

Then fetch the units from the database in descending order. Should give you the same array. Here's a query similar to what you will need:

```
SELECT id, units FROM article_sets WHERE article_id=XXX ORDER BY units DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to loop through the database
>   and check if session is equal session
>   output. if true, insert into db else,
>   redirect front

It sounds like you know what you want to do.

So what are you asking? Do you want someone to code it up for you?